# Amazon Athena table creation query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, create-table

I am testing out using Amazon Athena for small-mid sized data tables, but I'm running into an error with table creation.  I am trying to run the following query in the Athena Query editor:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`athenatest` (
    `year` int,
    `month` int,
    `date` date,
    `category` string,
    `category_id` string,
    `numb` float
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
    'serialization.format' = ',',
    'field.delim' = ',',
    'line.delim' = '\n'
)
LOCATION 's3://pmdataops-test/athena-test'
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'has_encrypted_data'='false',
    'skip.header.line.count' = 1
)
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
line 1:8: mismatched input 'EXTERNAL'. Expecting: 'OR', 'SCHEMA', 'TABLE', 'VIEW'
```

So far, I've taken a look at the Athena documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html

But I can't seem to identify the error(s) - does anyone know what's wrong?  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
Did a little testing on my side - looks like the error is coming from this line:

`'skip.header.line.count' = 1`

Removing that line makes the query run successfully.  Does anyone know the proper method for skipping lines?  We're planning on using csv data, so we'd just need to skip the header row each time.

Edit2:
Double-checked the documentation, looks like there I was missing some quotes in that line, running it with the following successfully completes the query:

`'skip.header.line.count'='1'`

Comment: Could you check if removing the backticks from `\`test\`.\`athenatest\`` works?

Comment: Afraid not - still getting the same error code when I use ```test.athenatest```